Stored procedure execution error: uninitialized resultSet and i don't understand why
The following task results in an error:

Stored procedure execution error: uninitialized resultset

and I don't understand why.
This is the code:
DECLARE
    response_string STRING;
    result BOOLEAN;
    select_statement VARCHAR;
    stream_result resultset;
    query_result resultset;
    c1 CURSOR FOR stream_result;
    c2 CURSOR FOR query_result;
BEGIN
    IF (SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') = true) THEN select_statement := 'SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 ORDER BY process_date';
    ELSEIF (SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2') = true) THEN select_statement := 'SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_2 ORDER BY process_date';
    END IF;
 
  stream_result := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
 
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
        query_result := (SELECT stg.flag FROM db.schema.status_loads stg WHERE row_variable.process_date = stg.process_date);
        FOR row_variable_2 IN c2 DO
            IF (row_variable_2.flag = 1) THEN
                result := true;
            ELSE    
                result := false;
                BREAK inner_loop;
            END IF;
        END FOR inner_loop;
        IF (:result = true) THEN
            response_string := (call sp_1(row_variable.process_date));
            RETURN(:response_string);
        ELSE 
            RETURN(row_variable.process_date);
        END IF;
    END FOR outer_loop;


does the script only run when one of those 2 streams have data, because you don't have a select_statement being created when they are both false.

hi @MikeWalton yes, the task is executed when either stream_1 or stream_2 or both has data
